# How know to if an application was installed using apt-get or not?

Tags: firefox, 15.10

I would like to know (I can't remember) if I installed Firefox and other applications using apt-get or if I download them from their official site and installed them manually. How to know that?

Answer (score 0):

The apt-mark command offers what you want:

```
apt-mark showmanual firefox
```

will list "firefox" if it was installed manually.
See the man pages for further capabilities"

```
man apt-mark
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out if an application was installed by package manager (`dpkg`, `apt-get` etc.) or other means (compiled from source, pre-compiled binary etc.):

```
if dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep -w APPNAME &> /dev/null
    then
        echo 'yes'
    else
        echo 'no'
fi
```

**Note:** Replace `APPNAME` with the actual application name.

Returns `yes` if installed through the package manager else `no`. Note: it will return `no` even if the package is not installed *at all*.

One-liner version:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall | grep -w APPNAME &> /dev/null || echo 'no' && echo 'yes'
```

**Note:** Again, replace `APPNAME` with actual application name.

You can add it as a function in your `.bashrc`.

Comment: thanks! and how to know if it was installed using `apt-get` or  `dpgk` specifically?

Comment: @tirengarfio I don't think there is a way, since `apt-get` is basically an easier front-end for `dpkg`.

Comment: I have installed Firefox and I don't know if I installed it using `dpkg` or `apt-get`, so I don't know know what to do to uninstall it. Does the the way to uninstall it depends on the way I installed it (`apt-get` or `dpkg`)?

Comment: @tirengarfio No, you can uninstall either way (though I recommend the `apt-get` way, since it automatically resolves any errors).